# Create custom interface for telegram web app bot with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, bots, telegram, chatbot

I'm wondering how Can WE design an interface for telegram web app bot.
As mentionned in their site , there is a possibility to do that with BotApi with JavaScript , but it's not clear
It's liké there are somme thèmes available and WE Can customisé them
But why JavaScript is needed ? How Can WE create ower own interface with JavaScript ?
Link to the section in telegram website :
https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#color-schemes

Comment: I think [Telegram Database Library](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib) would be the place for you to start.

Comment: I need juste to customisé interface in telgram botthat i cited in thé article